# Are Wndproc and hook in the main thread?

Tags: c, windows

Sorry for my dumb question, but are wndproc and hooks in the main thread (when called)?

If they are does it mean I can not use them for build buffer for keyboard input?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your window procedure (and any subclassed window procedures, hooks, etc) run in the thread which called `CreateWindow` (it's a requirement for that same thread to later process the message queue, window procedures actually run when your main message dispatch loop calls `DispatchMessage`).

Not sure what you mean by "build buffer for keyboard input".